# Passing state info into a service worker before `install`

Tags: javascript, service-worker

**Background**

I'm new to service workers but working on a [library](https://github.com/brettz9/textbrowser) that is intended to become "offline-first" (really, almost "offline-only") (FWIW, the intent is to allow consumers of the library to provide JSON config representing tabular multilinear texts and get in return an app which allows their users to browse these texts in a highly customizable manner by paragraph/verse ranges.)

Other projects are to install the library as a dependency and then supply information via our JavaScript API such as the path of a JSON config file indicating the files that our app will consume to produce an (offline) app for them.

While I know we could do any of the following:

1. require users provide a hard-coded path from which our service worker's `install` script could use `waitUntil` with its own JSON request to retrieve the user's necessary files
2. skip the service worker's `install` step of the service worker for the JSON file, and rely on `fetch` events to update the cache, providing a fallback display if the user completed the install and went offline before the fetches could occur.
3. Post some state info from our main script to a server which the service worker, once registered, would query before completing its `install` event.

...but all choices seems less than ideal because, respectively:

1. Our library's consumers may prefer to be able to designate their own location for their JSON config.
2. Given that the JSON config designates files critical to showing their users anything useful, I'd rather not allow an install to complete only to say that the user has to go back online to get the rest of the files if they were not able to remain online after the `install` event to see all the required fetches occur.
3. Besides wanting to avoid more trips to the server and extra code, I'd prefer for our code to be so offline-oriented as to be able to work entirely on mere static file servers.

**Question:**

Is there some way to pass a message or state information into a service worker *before* the `install` event occurs, whether as part of the query string of the service worker URL, or through a messaging event? The messaging event could even technically arrive after the `install` event begins as long as it can occur before a `waitUntil` within the `install` is complete.

I know I could test this myself, but I'd like to know what best practices might be anyways when the critical app files must themselves be dynamically obtained as in such libraries as ours.

I'm guessing `indexedDB` might be the sole alternative here (i.e., saving the config info or path of the JSON config to indexedDB, registering a service worker, and retrieving the indexedDB data from within the `install` event)? Even this would not be ideal as I'm letting users define a namespace for their storage, but I need a way for it too to be passed into the worker, or otherwise, multiple such apps on the origin could clash.

Comment: **TL,DR** ; Did you try putting your logic within `.waitUntil` block.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari : I posted a reply that shows `waitUntil` can be used as part of the solution with messaging if that's what you were getting at.

Comment: Exactly what I meant..

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### Using a Query Parameter

If you find it useful, then yes, you can provide state during service worker installation by including a query parameter to your service worker when you register it, like so:

```
// Inside your main page:
const pathToJson = '/path/to/file.json';
const swUrl = '/sw.js?pathToJson=' + encodeURIComponent(pathToJson);
navigator.serviceWorker.register(swUrl);

// Inside your sw.js:
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  const pathToJson = new URL(location).searchParams.get('pathToJson');
  event.waitUntil(
    fetch(pathToJson)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonData => /* Do something with jsonData */)
  );
});
```

A few things to note about this approach:

- If you `fetch()` the JSON file in your `install` handler (as in the code sample), that will effectively happen once per version of your service worker script (`sw.js`). If the contents of the JSON file change, but everything else stays the same, the service worker won't automatically detect that and repopulate your caches.
- Following from the first point, if you work around that by, e.g., including hash-based versioning in your JSON file's URL, each time you change that URL, you'll end up installing a new service worker. This isn't a bad thing, per se, but you need to keep it in mind if you have logic in your web app that listens for service worker lifecycle events.

### Alternative Approaches

You also might find it easier to just add files to your caches from within the context of your main page, since browsers that support the Cache Storage API expose it via `window.caches`. Precaching the files within the `install` handler of a service worker does have the advantage of ensuring that all the files have been cached successfully before the service worker installs, though.

Another approach is to write the state information to IndexedDB from the `window` context, and then read from IndexedDB inside of your service worker's `install` handler.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 3:**

And since it is not supposed to be safe to rely on globals within the worker, my messaging solution seems even less sound. I think it either has to be Jeff Posnick's solution (in some cases, `importScripts` may work).

**Update 2:**

Although not directly related to the topic of this thread relating to "install" event, as per a discussion starting at https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/659#issuecomment-384919053 , there are some issues, particularly with using this message-passing approach for the `activate` event. Namely, the `activate` event may never fail, and thus never be tried again, leaving one's application in an unstable state. (A failure of `install` will at least not apply the new service worker to old pages, whereas `activate` will keep fetches on hold until the event completes, which it may never do if it is left waiting for a message that was not received, and which anything but a new worker will fail to correct since new pages won't be able to load to send that message again.)

**Update:**

Although I got the client from within the `install` script in Chrome, I wasn't able to receive the message back with `navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage` for some reason.

However, I was able to fully confirm the following approach in its place:

**In the service worker:**

```
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            self.addEventListener('message', ({data: {
                myData
            }}) => {
                // Do something with `myData` here
                //    then when ready, `resolve`
            });
        })
    );
 });
```

**In the calling script:**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then((r) => {
    r.installing.postMessage({myData: 100});
});
```

---

@JeffPosnick 's is the best answer for the simple case I described in the OP, but I thought I'd present my discovering that one can get messages from and into a service worker script early (tested on Chrome) by such as the following:

**In the service worker**:

```
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil(self.clients.matchAll({
        includeUncontrolled: true,
        type: 'window'
    }).then((clients) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (clients && clients.length) {
            const client = clients.pop();
            client.postMessage('send msg to main script');
            // One should presumably be able to poll to check for a
            //   variable set in the SW message listener below
            //   and then `resolve` when set
            // Despite the unreliability of setting globals in SW's
            //   I believe this could be safe here as the `install`
            //   event is to run while the main script is still open.
        }
    })));
});

self.addEventListener('message', e => {
    console.log('SW receiving main script msg', e.data);
    e.ports[0].postMessage('sw response');
});
```

**In the calling script:**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    console.log('msg recd in main script', e.data);
    e.source.postMessage('sending back to sw');
});
return navigator.serviceWorker.register(
    'sw.js'
).then((r) => {
    // navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((r) => { // This had been necessary at some point in my testing (with r.active.postMessage), but not working for me atm...
        // Sending a subsequent message
        const messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
        messageChannel.port1.onmessage = (e) => {
            if (e.data.error) {
                console.log('err', e.data.error);
            } else {
                console.log('data', e.data);
            }
        };
        navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('sending to sw', [messageChannel.port2]);
    // });
});
```