# Relay information to the service worker on install

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a PWA with multiple different languages and would like to cache only language specific files on install. I can't find out a way to communicate the language to the service worker during install. Ideas on how I could do it?

My js code to initiate the service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('../service-worker.js', { scope: '/' }).then((reg) => {
    console.log('Service worker registered successfully.', reg);
    registration = reg;
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
});
```

My code in the service-worker.js:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    messageAllClients('Event-Install');
    // Perform install steps
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
            messageAllClients('Language detected by the service worker: '+language);
            messageAllClients('Pre-caching offline page');
            return cache.addAll(FILES_TO_CACHE);
        })
    );
    self.skipWaiting();
});
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444379/385997

Comment: Thanks, @JeffPosnick! That was exactly what I was looking for, but failed to find with my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables can be relayed to the service worker during install [via GET attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444379/385997), as @JeffPosnick pointed out in the comment.